# Inform ViewModel of Model update?

Tags: android, mvvm, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-databinding

I am currently working on an app that uses Firebase's real-time database and data binding for displaying. To keep it simple, here's a simple version of the problem:

Given a model class:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public Date getDate() { return date; }
    public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
}
```

And a ViewModel class for the users:

```
public class UserViewModel {
    private User user;
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getName() { return user.getName() }
    public void setName(String name) { user.setName(name); }
    public String getDateAsString() { // ... }
}
```

Now, in the activity/fragment I have a `RecyclerView` rendering a list of users. So within the adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` I inflate a layout using `DataBindingUtils`, create a new `ViewHolder` and a new `UserViewModel` instance which accesses the UI. In onBindViewHolder() the `UserViewModel` gets assigned with the according User instance.

So far, so good: Given a list of users, its items get rendered into the `RecyclerView` through the `UserViewModel`.

For the app, I also use Firebase to read and write to the Realtime database. So when I now get a callback that a `User` entry has been updated, I directly modify the infos in the according instance.

So now to the question: **How do I inform the `UserViewModel` that the data has changed and that it needs to redraw the according views in the UI?**

I know one step I need to do is to have `UserViewModel` extend `BaseObservable`, mark the methods with `@Bindable` and add calls to `notifyPropertyChanged(int)` in the setters of the ViewModel. But this doesn't solve the problem of how to inform the `UserViewModel` of an update to the model data.

Any help and example code is appreciated! Thx! :)

Comment: As I understand this question, it is more related to firebase, right? How do you get a notification from firebase when `user` changes. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried to use `@={viewModel.name}` with everything you have here?

Comment: @GeorgeMount it isn't specifically related to Firebase. It could be an RxJava call or anything that will return a {{User}} object with updated info to a local one. The info I get from the server will just have to be changed directly in the model and what I need is to update the UI in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to extend `UserViewModel` with `BaseObservable`, but you can. I'll show another way how you can achieve this.

Personally, I prefer to create a `ObservableField<User>` in my `UserViewModel`, create getters and setters like:

```
private final ObservableField<User> userField = new ObservableField<User>();

public UserViewModel(User user){
    userField.set(user);
}

public ObservableField<User> getUser(){
    return userField;
}
```

pass it to the layout and reference the properties like this:

```
<variable
    name="userViewModel"
    type="your.package.UserViewModel" />

<EditText
    android:text"@={userViewModel.user.name}" />
```

Whenever your user changes his `Name` in your `EditText`, the changes are also updated in your model. (Using two-way databinding with `@={}`)

Updated to use the `ObservableField`, thanks for the heads up, @tynn. Correct me, if I'm still wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `ObservableField` at all? None of its properties is used here.

Comment: ... What? I think I do not understand you. I use a `ObservableField` from the android (native) databinding library to avoid creating a observable object.

Comment: Have a  look at the generated binding classes. This way you use your `UserViewModel` as a POJO and the binding uses the getter and setter of it and doesn't know anything of the `ObservableField`. Or try changing the user name in your view model and see if it's getting observed and changed in the UI.

Comment: Ah.. I see it now, it has been a while since I used this. It should be correct now, right..?

Comment: I just prefer to make the `ObservableField` public final, but like this it looks right to me too.

Comment: So does adding the user as ObservableField automatically let the ViewModel get informed on changes on the according User object? Or in the case of your project a change directly to a Memo object will inform the MemoListViewModel and update the view? I'll have to try to implement it that way tonight. Thx so far! :) I'll update on my progress

Comment: Yes, it should do that. How is it going? Maybe you can... accept my answer then? :)

Comment: The project is not there anymore!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can take a look at using RxJava/RxAndroid to subscribe your viewModel to changes in the model class or the firebase instance (they should be observable). So for example, as you want to let the viewModel know that the firebase has a new user and that a user entry has been updated, you can call the viewModels onNext method from that callback, which will notify the viewModel subscribed to it, and run the method you want to run (like fetching the data), then with base observable you can then notify your list.